# How to return multiple variables from one test case to another using Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

TC1: 01_UserManagement/Login

```
String u = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('SignInPage/txt_username'), 'placeholder')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('SignInPage/txt_username'), username)

String p = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('SignInPage/txt_password'), 'placeholder')

CustomKeywords.'com.fcm.utilities.ClearTextField.ClearText'(findTestObject('SignInPage/txt_password'))

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('SignInPage/txt_password'), password)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('SignInPage/btn_signinButton'))

Map map = [:]
map.put('inlinetextofusername',u)
map.put('inlinetextofpassword',p)
map.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
return map;
```

TestCase2:

```
Map TC_1_called = WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('01_UserManagement/Login'), [('username') : 'Anna', ('password') : 'Analyst_2017',('inlinetextofusername'):'',('inlinetextofpassword'):''], 
    FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

println(TC_1_called[inlinetextofusername])

println(TC_1_called[inlinetextofpassword]
```

I am getting following error:-

> 12-11-2017 04:31:40 PM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/01_UserManagement/Logout FAILED because (of) Variable 'inlinetextofusername' is not defined for test case.

How to take the values which is stored in Map in Test case 1 and to use in Test Case 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map TC_1_called = WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('01_UserManagement/Login'), [('username') : 'Anna', ('password') : 'Analyst_2017',('map'):''], 
    FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
```

This returns values..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass values from one test case to another in Katalon Studio, you should pass these values from `Test Case A` to `Test Case B`

Imagine you have these test cases `Log in test` and `Dashboard test` and you need to pass `username` and `email` from `Log in test`to `Dashboard test`

Go to script mode in `Log in test` and at the end of script add this line of code

```
WebUI.callTestCase( findTestCase('Test Cases/dashboard test')  , [('username'): username, ('email'):email]  )
```

This will pass local variables `username` and `email` from `Log in test` script to `dashboard test`

**Notice**: before applying this method, you should create test case variables to the second test case `dashboard test` from `variables` tab beside `script` tab in the lower section of test case editor.

Hope this comes in handy

Answer (score -1):

I have issue on passing variable that has a random value to another test case.

Solution: I created a Global Variable with empty string then I set that Global Variable on my testCase_1 with a random value. I can now call that Global Variable to my testCase_2 without calling testCase_1. But you must execute testCase_1 first on your test suite.

testCase_1:

GlobalVariable.randomString = yourRandomValue

testCase_2:

String variableFromTestCase_1 = GlobalVariable.randomString

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgXvP.png)